# Is there anything in .NET that gets the abbreviation of all weekdays specific to culture?

Tags: c#, datetime

I need the weekdays abbreviation in different cultures. I have it in spanish already (hardcoded). Are there something already in .NET that has it already?

```
 //string[] days = { "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jeuves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo" };



    string[] days = { "L", "M", "X", "J", "V", "S", "D" };
```

Comment: As side note this `DateTime.Now.ToString("ddd", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)` will give you the abreviation in the selected culture for a date. Take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're probably looking for [`DateTimeFormatInfo.AbbreviatedDayNames`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.abbreviateddaynames%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> Gets or sets a one-dimensional array of type String containing the culture-specific abbreviated names of the days of the week.

or [`DateTimeFormatInfo.ShortestDayNames`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.shortestdaynames%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> Gets or sets a string array of the shortest unique abbreviated day names associated with the current DateTimeFormatInfo object.

For example:

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedDayNames
```

returns

[image]

on a `de-DE` system.

Comment: As a side note; `AbbreviatedDayNames` returns names _generally_ with `ddd` format, `ShortestDayNames`  returns names _generally_ with `dd` format.

Answer (score 4):

Try to observe the `CultureInfo`

```
var culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
var dayNames = culture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedDayNames;
var shortNames = culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortestDayNames;
...
```

And it is there for any culture:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("cs")
```